# jQuery Tabs with multiple content areas

Tags: jquery, tabs

I've searched around on stackoverflow and can't seem to find what i'm after. I'm looking to do a simple jQuery tabbed section. 1 lot of tabs controlling multiple content areas (rather than the standard 1 area that switches).

I'm using data- attribute, i've tried to use multiple enteries so i dont have repeat id's but to no avail.

Here's the jQuery for the tabs

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
})

var tab = $("li").data("tab").split(" ");
```

and the HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1 tab-5">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2 tab-6">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3 tab-7">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4 tab-8">Tab Four</li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    First content area
</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
     Second content area
</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    Third content area
</div>
<div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
    Forth content area
</div>

<div id="tab-5" class="tab-content current">
    First content area
</div>
<div id="tab-6" class="tab-content">
     Second content area
</div>
<div id="tab-7" class="tab-content">
    Third content area
</div>
<div id="tab-8" class="tab-content">
    Forth content area
</div>
```

So intial load is fine but when you click on any tab the 2nd content area disappears rather than switching like the first content area.

ANy ideas?

Here's a working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alexgomy/9tqra6ze/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Solution without id's (https://jsfiddle.net/L24qrbpj):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("."+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })
})
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.tabs li.current {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #222;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 15px;
  margin:0 0 30px;
}
.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

 <ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
 </ul>

 <div class="tab-1 tab-content current">
  First content area
 </div>
 <div class="tab-2 tab-content">
   Second content area
 </div>
 <div class="tab-3 tab-content">
  Third content area
 </div>
 <div class="tab-4 tab-content">
  Forth content area
 </div>
  
  <div class="tab-1 tab-content current">
  First content area AVB
 </div>
 <div class="tab-2 tab-content">
   Second content area AVB
 </div>
 <div class="tab-3 tab-content">
  Third content area AVB
 </div>
 <div class="tab-4 tab-content">
  Forth content area AVB
 </div>

</div><!-- container -->
```

Comment: Such an obvious solution. Thank you.

Comment: I thing using jsfiddle isn't good idea when stackoverflow has snippet

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
$('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
$('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
```

Will hide the showing content when clicking on any tab.

And you can use toogleClass on controlling what to be displayed.

Here is a worked sample

https://jsfiddle.net/dwf1jsgq/

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    var tab = $(this).data("tab").split(" ");
    for(var i=0; i < tab.length; i++)
    {
     $("#"+tab[i]).addClass('current');
    
    }
    
})
})
```

```css
body{
   margin-top: 100px;
   line-height: 1.6
  }
  .container{
   width: 800px;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }



  ul.tabs{
   margin: 0 0 20px;
   padding: 0px;
   list-style: none;
  }
  ul.tabs li{
   background: none;
   color: #222;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   cursor: pointer;
  }

  ul.tabs li.current{
   background: #ededed;
   color: #222;
  }

  .tab-content{
   display: none;
   background: #ededed;
   padding: 15px;
      margin:0 0 30px;
  }

  .tab-content.current{
   display: inherit;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1 tab-5">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2 tab-6">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3 tab-7">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4 tab-8">Tab Four</li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    First content area
</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
     Second content area
</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    Third content area
</div>
<div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
    Forth content area
</div>

<div id="tab-5" class="tab-content current">
    First content area
</div>
<div id="tab-6" class="tab-content">
     Second content area
</div>
<div id="tab-7" class="tab-content">
    Third content area
</div>
<div id="tab-8" class="tab-content">
    Forth content area
</div>
```

I hope you need like this

Comment: You should have edited the initial answer, instead of copying and making it as a snippet.